# gRPC ServerInterceptor with Armeria

Tags: grpc-java, armeria

I am using Armeria with gRPC/java and I'm looking to decorate one of the services with an AuthService like this https://sultanov.dev/blog/securing-java-grpc-services-with-jwt-based-authentication/. I want to access the gRPC request header, do some validation, and if validated, write something in the context object and proceed.

I am having some trouble finding documentation for how to interact with the context object correctly. Can someone help point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an Armeria decorator to intercept the call and validate it:
https://armeria.dev/docs/server-decorator#extending-simpledecoratinghttpservice-and-simpledecoratingrpcservice

It's beneficial when you need to make another asynchronous call in the intercepting logic because it's not easy to do that with a gRPC interceptor.

You can write something to `RequestContext` in the decorator.
https://armeria.dev/docs/advanced-custom-attributes#requestcontext-custom-attributes
You can retrieve it in your service via `RequestContext.current()` later.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Extended `SimpleDecoratingHttpService` and used that to decorate my gRPC services

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/example-jwt-auth/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/jwtauth/JwtServerInterceptor.java#L33) out. This shows how to get the JWT from the metadata (request header) and set some value into the context accordingly.

Comment: Seems that this context is not working with Armeria, but I'll keep this in mind next time I'm building something without Armeria, thanks!